# nginx redirect www to non-www not working over https, only over http

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

✅ http://example.com        https://example.com

✅ http://www.example.com    https://example.com

✅ https://example.com       https://example.com

❌ https://www.example.com   https://example.com - The site loads, but I just want the www gone.

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 404;

}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

I have two A records pointing to my IP, nothing else.

‍♂️

Comment: Great that you were able to figure it out. But please post your solution as an answer and accept it instead of editing it into your question, otherwise the question will stay as "unsolved" in the system forever.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, my last two blocks were wrong:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.ai example.ai;
    return 301 https://example.ai$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ai/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ai/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    server_name www.example.ai;
    return 301 https://example.ai$request_uri;
}
```